# xpath: finding a following node

Tags: xpath

I have a html table structure: two columns, the left for the label and the right with a checkbox. Thereare **multiple** checkboxes on the page.

I'm trying to write the xpath to locate a particular label in the left column then locate the corresponding checkbox in the right column on that row.

The html table is as below:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Label 1</td>
<td>
<input type=checkbox name="dynamic_checkbox_name">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The checkbox name is dynamic otherwise I would have located the element with it.

Thanks a lot.

I have tried:
`//td[text()='Label']` - which selects the correct td, but I don't know how to select the next td that follows this...?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show I can select the td with 'Label 1' but need to know how to chain the xpath to select the next non child td in the document...

Answer (score 2):

You want to select the following `td` sibling, which can be done like this:

```
//td[.='Label 1']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Or, to get the checkbox itself:

```
//td[.='Label 1']/following-sibling::td[1]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `//input[@type='checkbox']` should work if it's the only input on the page.

If not, you can be more specific and select the input which is in a td which is in a tr which is in the table with `/table/tr/td/input[@type='checkbox']`

Or something like that, I haven't tried it.